# Completed Hochschild (co)homology

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$ algebra (not necessarily commutative). The Hochschild homology is then defined via a bar construction and that $HH_0(A)=A/[A,A]$. Note that each $HH_i(A)$ is a $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$-module. We can define $\overline{HH_0}(A):=A/\overline{[A,A]}$, where the overline means taking the $h$-adic completion. I want to ask if there is a version of the bar resolution that produces the 'completed' version of $HH$ and how $\overline{HH_i}$ and $HH_i$ are related and when they are equal.

Edit: More assumptions on $A$ might be needed to make the question 'nice'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book:

Hübl, Reinhold:
*Traces of differential forms and Hochschild homology*.
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, **1368**. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1989.

treats the case of Hochschild co/homology for topological algebras. In the first chapter it gives an introduction to the basic constructions in the topological case.

Comment: This is for commutative algebra though. In fact there is also a paper titled 'Hochschild cohomology commutes with completion' or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps the techniques carry over. At least when the base ring is commutative. I wonder if you want HH over $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$ or just over $\mathbb{C}$. They are quite different objects.